# How can I use torch's `VHP` routine inside of the `step` method when defining a custom optimizer?

Tags: optimization, pytorch, autodiff

So I have been playing around with implementing an optimizer that leverages the hessian-vector product in it's update rule inside of torch --- I am keen on using the existing [`VHP`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.vhp.html) for the same, but it's really awkward API makes it impossible to be used inside of the `step` method when defining a custom optimizer class in torch.

Here are the problems that I currently have with the existing `VHP` interface:

1. One typically does not pass in any argument to the `step` method when making the call to `optimizer.step()`, *except* in the case of algorithms like `L-BFGS` which require a `closure` argument since they re-evaluate the loss function multiple times every iteration. Given the API for the VHP, a typical call to the method would look something like: `VHP(loss_func, (model_output_tensor, gt_labels/values_tensor), v)` (I have gripes about this signature as well, which I explain in the next point). But `step` does *not* typically have access to *any* of these arguments! `step` doesn't have any idea about `loss_func, model_output_tensor, gt_labels` --- so just to get it to work I decided to dump all of these arguments inside of `closure` (horrible choice, but that seemed to be the only way out) but then...
2. It seems like the way `VHP` treats the `inputs` tuple is as separate inputs to the function that are to be evaluated independently (that is why they explicitly impose `len(inputs) == len(v)`), but loss functions almost always take in vector inputs and I have no clue how one could pass in *two* vector inputs in a single tensor (except maybe by vertically stacking the inputs, but I am unsure if `VHP` would parse the inputs that way).

TLDR: The API for torch's `VHP` method is *really* hard to work with when defining a custom optimizer in torch --- are there any interesting alternatives for computing the Hessian-Vector-Product that do *not* run into the pitfalls that I mentioned above? As far as I am aware `JAX` also has an identical API for their own `HVP` method.

Thank you for your time!